# Regular expression to split string with PHP preg_split with values containing the delimiter itself

Tags: php, regex

What is the correct regular expression to archive the desired result? Hence, empty fields in $str may or may not be surrounded by `""`

```
$str='"Value","Value, containing delimiter","","End"';
$regEx="/,/";
print_r(preg_split($regEx,$str));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Value"
    [1] => "Value
    [2] =>  containing delimiter"
    [3] => ""
    [4] => "End"
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Value"
    [1] => "Value, containing delimiter"
    [2] => ""
    [3] => "End"
)
```

Comment: Why not use `str_getcsv`: https://3v4l.org/DZuhX ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm newbie, didn't know about it, so I took the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$str='"Value","Value, containing delimiter","","End"';
$regEx='/,s*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/'; 
print_r(preg_split($regEx,$str));
```

When run, the output is:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => "Value" 
        [1] => "Value, containing delimiter" 
        [2] => "" 
        [3] => "End"
)
```

Comment: It will give an undesired result on `'"Value",,"Value, containing delimiter","","End"'` if I understood OP correctly

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I need an clarification on that from OP, since I genuinely think he made a mistake when typing / copy-pasting the input string.

Comment: ok, got it: $regEx='/,\s*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/'; Thanks to @wiktor-stribiżew

Comment: I found some interesting results using this solution not sure how they fit OP's view though. An example code is [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7eb15b1e60e91514b5424c2577cc7315b7a992cc) also a very slight mod to original rexex removes the "interesting results". An updated exaple is [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/568a6477cfd6ea994d9e2f1ac121587dc650e10f).

Comment: To the downvoter, run the code, and see that it works exactly as the OP requested.